# How to get private playlist ids through YouTube API V3?

Tags: java, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a YouTube account which has 4 channels in it. I created private and public playlists in all channels but when i'm trying to get private playlist through OAuth process i couldn't get the private playlist ids only public playlist are displaying.Even i tried api explorer i could see the only public playlists not private  Below is my code please help me

```
Credential credential = getCredentials();    
youTube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("Playlist Web App").build();
    String channelID = getDefaultChannelId();
    YouTube.Search.List search = youTube.search().list("id,snippet");
    search.setChannelId(channelID);
    search.setType("playlist");
    search.setFields("items(id/playlistId,kind,snippet(title))");
    search.setMaxResults((long) 10);

    SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
    List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
    if (searchResultList != null) {
                Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults = searchResultList.iterator();
                if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
                }

                while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {

                    SearchResult playlist = iteratorSearchResults.next();
                    ResourceId rId = playlist.getId();

                    System.out.println(" Playlist Id : " + playlist.getId().getPlaylistId());
                    System.out.println(" Title: " + playlist.getSnippet().getTitle());


                }
       }
```

I followed the OAuth process but i couldn't get my own private playlists.

Answer (score 3):

Yes now I could able to get private playlists of my channels.
Instead of `YouTube.Search.List search = youTube.search().list("id,snippet");` and setting `search.setType("playlist");` It is better to go for YouTube.Playlists.List. Below sharing my code which may be useful for others

```
    Credential credential = getCredentials();
    youTube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("Playlist Web App").build();         
    YouTube.Playlists.List  searchList = youTube.playlists().list("id,snippet,contentDetails");     
    searchList.setFields("etag,eventId,items(contentDetails,etag,id,kind,player,snippet,status),kind,nextPageToken,pageInfo,prevPageToken,tokenPagination");
searchList.setMine(true);
searchList.setMaxResults((long) 10);
PlaylistListResponse playListResponse = searchList.execute();
List<Playlist> playlists = playListResponse.getItems();

   if (playlists != null) {
        Iterator<Playlist> iteratorPlaylistResults = playlists.iterator();
                        if (!iteratorPlaylistResults.hasNext()) {
                            System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
                        }    
                        while (iteratorPlaylistResults.hasNext()) {    
                            Playlist playlist = iteratorPlaylistResults.next();


                                System.out.println(" Playlist Id : " + playlist.getId());
                                System.out.println(" Title: " + playlist.getSnippet().getTitle());

                        }
                    }
```

for more services of YouTube go the following https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me where did you get YouTube and Credential, Is it some official Youtube SDK? can you share the link as current documentation do not have such SDK links.

Comment: Can you please include getCredentials method in example above. When I tried to use setMine(true) it did not worked and 400 bad request.